# Rank of a Group and Independence of Generators

Tags: group-theory, finitely-generated

Suppose $G$ is a finitely generated group which is generated by a set $S=\{a,b,\ldots\}$.

- I don't know terminology here but is there some kind of "orthogonality" or independence that could exist such that if the elements of $S$ are all independent, then $|S|=\operatorname{rank}(G)$?
- If such a notion of independence exists, how is it defined (and how is it called)?
- I believe it would essentially need to be a requirement that none of the elements can be generated by a combination of the others, but is that restriction enough to ensure $|S|=\operatorname{rank}(G)$ or could it still be larger?
- Is there a better definition or even a formula for such concept?

I don't believe any kind of pairwise independence could be used, since if you consider $S_3$, $\{(1,2),(2,3)\}$, $\{(1,2),(1,2,3)\}$, and $\{(2,3),(1,2,3)\}$  would all be S's such that $|S|=\operatorname{rank}(G)$, thus $(1,2),(2,3)$, and $(1,2,3)$ would all be pairwise independent, but then this would be another $S$ only with $|S|>\operatorname{rank}(G)$.

Comment: That depends, what is your definition of $\operatorname{Rank}(G)$?

Comment: By rank(G) I mean the smallest possible cardinality of a generating set of G

Comment: “No elements can be generated by a combination of the others” just means the set is a minimal generating set, but it does not suffice even in the case of finitely generated abelian groups, which have a well-defined notion of rank; for example, $\mathbb{Z}$ has rank $1$, but the set $S=\{2,3\}$ is a minimal generating set: no proper subset generates $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin would that condition suffice if G were finite?

Comment: No. $\{2,3\}$ is also a minimal generating set for $\mathbb{Z}_6$, which has rank 1.

Comment: In general, the rank of a group is a very hard thing to calculate, and is in general algorithmically undecidable given only a finite presentation. (But then again, so is basically everything else.) The correct analogy to vector spaces is *abelian* groups (which all vector spaces are), where then rank is very easy to calculate as is linear independence of a given set of elements. But as pointed out, linearly independent sets are not necessarily as small as the rank.

Answer (score 1):

In your case these are different concepts.

Generators are introduced when we analyze the group of rotations, e.g. of a regular n-gon on a plane (dihedral group). So generators are used to show or identify the internal structure of a group, its subgroups for example.

The degree of a linear (=vector space), or rank of a module is the number that gives a numeric value for the structure that we already know everything about. We know that it is a set, which has the scalar multiplication and addition etc.

That is, if you think about the degree of a vector space, a priori you pull a lot of machinery, field or ring axioms, independence of vectors, basis etc. Very specific. You do not need all these for an abstract group.